# MacOS Swift Push Button for Random Image

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I am trying to write code for a Mac app that displays a random image when a button is pressed. My code is as follows.

```
import Cocoa

var tapInt = 0

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: NSImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreDisplay: NSTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.view.wantsLayer = true

        tapInt = defaults.integer(forKey: "counterKey")
        scoreDisplay.stringValue = "\(tapInt)"
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonWasTapped(_ sender: NSButton) {
        tapInt += 1
        scoreDisplay.stringValue = "\(tapInt)"
        defaults.setValue(tapInt, forKey: "counterKey")

        let random = arc4random_uniform(85)
        switch(random){
            case 0: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo1.jpg")
                break
            case 1: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo2.jpg")
                break
            case 2: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo3.jpg")
                break
            case 3: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo4.jpg")
                break
            case 4: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo5.jpg")
                break
            case 5: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo6.jpg")
                break
            case 6: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo7.jpg")
                break
            case 7: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo8.jpg")
                break
            case 8: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo9.jpg")
                break
            case 9: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo10.jpg")
                break
            case 10: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo11.jpg")
                break
            case 11: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo12.jpg")
                break
            case 12: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo13.jpg")
                break
            case 13: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo14.jpg")
                break
            case 14: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo15.jpg")
                break
            case 15: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo16.jpg")
                break
            case 16: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo17.jpg")
                break
            case 17: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo18.jpg")
                break
            case 18: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo19.jpg")
                break
            case 19: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo20.jpg")
                break
            case 20: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo21.jpg")
                break
            case 21: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo22.jpg")
                break
            case 22: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo23.jpg")
                break
            case 23: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo24.jpg")
                break
            case 24: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo25.jpg")
                break
            case 25: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo26.jpg")
                break
            case 26: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo27.jpg")
                break
            case 27: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo28.jpg")
                break
            case 28: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo29.jpg")
                break
            case 29: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo30.jpg")
                break
            case 30: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo31.jpg")
                break
            case 31: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo32.jpg")
                break
            case 32: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo33.jpg")
                break
            case 33: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo34.jpg")
                break
            case 34: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo35.jpg")
                break
            case 35: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo36.jpg")
                break
            case 36: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo37.jpg")
                break
            case 37: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo38.jpg")
                break
            case 38: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo39.jpg")
                break
            case 39: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo40.jpg")
                break
            case 40: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo41.jpg")
                break
            case 41: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo42.jpg")
                break
            case 42: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo43.jpg")
                break
            case 43: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo44.jpg")
                break
            case 44: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo45.jpg")
                break
            case 45: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo46.jpg")
                break
            case 46: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo47.jpg")
                break
            case 47: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo48.jpg")
                break
            case 48: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo49.jpg")
                break
            case 49: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo50.jpg")
                break
            case 50: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo51.jpg")
                break
            case 51: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo52.jpg")
                break
            case 52: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo53.jpg")
                break
            case 53: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo54.jpg")
                break
            case 54: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo55.jpg")
                break
            case 55: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo56.jpg")
                break
            case 56: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo57.jpg")
                break
            case 57: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo58.jpg")
                break
            case 58: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo59.jpg")
                break
            case 59: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo60.jpg")
                break
            case 60: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo61.jpg")
                break
            case 61: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo62.jpg")
                break
            case 62: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo63.jpg")
                break
            case 63: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo64.jpg")
                break
            case 64: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo65.jpg")
                break
            case 65: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo66.jpg")
                break
            case 66: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo67.jpg")
                break
            case 67: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo68.jpg")
                break
            case 68: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo69.jpg")
                break
            case 69: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo70.jpg")
                break
            case 70: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo71.jpg")
                break
            case 71: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo72.jpg")
                break
            case 72: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo73.jpg")
                break
            case 73: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo74.jpg")
                break
            case 74: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo75.jpg")
                break
            case 75: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo76.jpg")
                break
            case 76: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo77.jpg")
                break
            case 77: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo78.jpg")
                break
            case 78: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo79.jpg")
                break
            case 79: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo80.jpg")
                break
            case 80: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo81.jpg")
                break
            case 81: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo82.jpg")
                break
            case 82: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo83.jpg")
                break
            case 83: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo84.jpg")
                break
            case 84: imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo85.jpg")
                break
            default:
                break
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I run the code and then press the button, it doesn't display anything. I set the `imageView` to an image in my assets and then pressed the button and it changed it from the image I chose to a blank image view. I have made an array with (some of) my images in and have the random function, as follows:

```
let doggoImagesArray = [
    "doggo1.jpg",
    "doggo2.jpg",
    "doggo3.jpg",
    "doggo4.jpg",
    "doggo5.jpg",
    "doggo6.jpg",
    "doggo7.jpg",
    "doggo8.jpg",
    "doggo9.jpg",
    "doggo10.jpg",
    "doggo11.jpg",
    "doggo12.jpg",
    "doggo13.jpg",
    "doggo14.jpg",
    "doggo15.jpg",
    "doggo16.jpg",
    "doggo18.jpg",
    "doggo19.jpg",
    "doggo20.jpg",
    "doggo21.jpg",
    "doggo22.jpg",
    "doggo23.jpg",
    "doggo24.jpg",
    "doggo25.jpg",
    "doggo26.jpg",
    "doggo27.jpg",
    "doggo28.jpg",
    "doggo29.jpg",
    "doggo30.jpg",
    "doggo31.jpg",
    "doggo32.jpg",
    "doggo33.jpg"
]

func randomDoggoImage() -> NSImage {
    let unsignedArrayCount = UInt32(doggoImagesArray.count)
    let unsignedRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(unsignedArrayCount)
    let randomNumber = Int(unsignedRandomNumber)
    return NSImage(named: doggoImagesArray[randomNumber])!
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Try it without the jpg extension?

Comment: Are your images included in the bundle (are they copied to bundle or their are in assets file)? Check build phases->copy bundle resources. Is your imageView linked or it's nil?

Answer (score 0):

In your switch you don't set the image, you just compare if the image set is one you need. Just do:

```
@IBAction func buttonWasTapped(_ sender: NSButton) {
    tapInt += 1
    scoreDisplay.stringValue = "\(tapInt)"
    defaults.setValue(tapInt, forKey: "counterKey")
    imageView.image = randomDoggoImage()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your images are probably named without extensions `.jpg`

```
NSImage(named: "doggo1")
```

---

Anyway, your logic can be simplified a lot. You can delete your array and switch

```
@IBAction func buttonWasTapped(_ sender: NSButton) {
    tapInt += 1
    scoreDisplay.stringValue = "\(tapInt)"
    defaults.setValue(tapInt, forKey: "counterKey")

    imageView.image = NSImage(named: "doggo\(Int.random(in: 1...84))") // or 1...33
}
```